# Python linalg package not found?

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to python installation and have run into the following issue with a simple script  trying to read in a package.

```
:> python interptime.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interptime.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scipy import interpolate
  File "/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    from rbf import Rbf
  File "/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py", line 49, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg
  File "/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from basic import *
  File "/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import calc_lwork
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/calc_lwork.so, 2): Symbol not found: _ilaenv_
  Referenced from: /usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/calc_lwork.so
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
```

Here is the beginning of interptime.py script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
...
```

How can I tell python where to look for the scipy/linalg package?

Comment: Are you building from source?

Comment: I have installed the scisoft package which comes with the python tree, as indicated in the error message, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: It's not a Python problem. There is a mismatch in the linear algebra libraries, between what linalg expects and what is on your system. Which scisoft version did you install, from where, and which Mac OS version are you on?

Comment: I have Scisoft_OSX_macintel_2013.6.1.pkg installed.

Comment: Oh, the OS X version isn't even available outside the ESO network. Maybe you should contact a maintainer at ESO with your problem? I'm still guessing it's a problem with what OS version you have an what they expect.

Answer (score -2):

Python looks for the installed packages in the PYTHON_PATH environment variable. But I am not sure if that is your problem here. The error message suggests that there is a problem with the shared object versions... I would recommend you that you install everything you need with the pip install command on the console...

Comment: sorry, no. pip installing scipy on a OS X is not a very good idea. Better follow the install instructions at http://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: In fact, I'm only guessing (last line in the OP traceback). In fact, pip installing can be problematic even on *nix, since it does not always do the right thing (tm) with non-python dependencies. Eg BLAS/LAPACK (which is --- more guessing --- a problem here)

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH gives
/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages//

Comment: I have tried to install a separate version of python with Macports, but that's supposed to be located in /opt/local, no? Have I overwritten/relinked something by doing that?

Comment: That's possible... The error indicates that python found a part of a library (the shared object) but that the library is missing a function... I have seen this error many time in c/c++ Programms, when the version differs... But I am not familiar with Mac, so I am only guessing what could be wrong with your installation ;-)

Comment: Alright, I figured it out! For reference, there was a conflicting declaration in my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to a separate ATLAS library containing linalg which was compiled with 32-bit.